# Bootstrap: How do you open all the submenus to left side in Dropdown 4 and 5?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this example. Any suggestions, please ?

Navbar with submenus
https://codepen.io/jstneg/pen/pvyYdw

CSS:

```
.dropdown-submenu{ position: relative; }
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{
  top:0;
  left:100%; <!-- i was trying change for negative(any value) -->
  margin-top:-6px;
  margin-left:-1px;
  -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

Comment: is my answer handle it?

Comment: Thank you very much @AbdurrahmanY :D

Comment: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right you can add following lines the css class:

```
left: auto;
right: 100%;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: -1px;
```

The css class must be like this:

```css
.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu{
  top:0;
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top:-6px; 
  -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
}
```